# Mobile Push Notification provider with custom SDK

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, push

We would like to use a popular push notification provider(e.g aws/OneSignal..) but keeping our own SDK.

Could you recommend on provider that doesnt require to use it's SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Pushbots:

Below is the link , it's so simple and user friendly

[Pushbots link](https://pushbots.com/)

Comment: but still, how can I use my own SDK for that?